# SWIFT: UITableViewCell is initialised before its properties are set in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, tvos

I have this `UITableViewCell`:

```
class TableViewCell3: UITableViewCell {
    var sectionLabel: String?
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupLabel()
    }

    func setupLabel() {
        let myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
        // App crashes here because sectionLabel is nil
        myTextField.text = sectionLabel!
        self.contentView.addSubview(myTextField)
    }
}
```

As you see, I am trying to display a `UITextField` inside each `UITableViewCell`.
The property `sectionLabel` that I'm trying to display, is set inside the `UITableView`:

```
extension MoviesViewController5: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? sectionTableCell2
            else {
                fatalError("Unable to create explore table view cell")}

        cell.sectionLabel = sectionsLabels![indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `UITableViewCell` gets initialised before the `sectionLabel` property is set.
So when I try to display it:

```
   myTextField.text = sectionLabel!
```

The app crashes since it's `nil`.
Yes, I do know that I should add `nil` check but that's not the point.
The **POINT** is how do display the `UItextField` **AFTER** the `sectionLabel` property is set.

Comment: Why not use `didSet` on `sectionLabel`, and it will add the value then. Also, you shouldn't need to unwrap the value, since you can put nil in the `.text` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better just setup `UITextfield` in the initializer and set its text when the `sectionLabel` is updated.

```
class TableViewCell3: UITableViewCell {

    private var myTextField: UITextField?

    var sectionLabel: String? {
        didSet {
             self.myTextField?.text = self.sectionLabel
        }
    }
 
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupLabel()
    }

    func setupLabel() {
        myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
        self.contentView.addSubview(myTextField!)
    }
}
```